# How to format ZF2 DateSelect "day" element to 2 digits?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form2

I am wanting to do a date of birth composite drop-down for date of birth (i.e. three drop-downs - one for day, one for month, one for year). Helpfully, ZF2 comes with this element built in, called `DateSelect`

Here is how I am adding it to the form:

```
    $this->add([
        'name' => 'date_of_birth',
        'type' => 'DateSelect',
        'attributes' => [
            'required' => true,
            'value' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('18 years ago')),
        ],
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Date of Birth',
            'max_year' => date('Y', strtotime('18 years ago')),
        ],
    ]);
```

To render the form I am doing:

```
echo $this->form($form);
```

Anyway, the `day` element is being rendered in [`j` format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) (i.e. day of the month without leading zeros   `1` to `31`).

How do I tell the element to render the day in `d` format (i.e. day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros   `01` to `31`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view helper `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormDateSelect` has a function `getPattern` that generates the patten by using the `IntlDateFormatter` class:

```
$intl           = new IntlDateFormatter($this->getLocale(), $this->dateType, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$this->pattern  = $intl->getPattern();
```

There did not appear to be any method of setting a pattern at element level, so I have extended this view helper allowing me to specify my own pattern:

```
<?php
namespace RPK\Form\View\Helper;

use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormDateSelect as ZendFormDateSelect;

class FormDateSelect extends ZendFormDateSelect
{
    /**
     * Parse the pattern
     *
     * @param  bool $renderDelimiters
     * @return array
     */
    protected function parsePattern($renderDelimiters = true)
    {
        //Replace `day` value of "d" with "dd"
        $pattern = parent::parsePattern($renderDelimiters);
        if($pattern['day'] === 'd') {
            $pattern['day'] = 'dd';
        }
        return $pattern;
    }
}
```

Very basically, this takes the returned pattern array (`['day'=>'d', 'month' => 'MMMM', 'year' => 'yyyy']`), checks if the value of `day` is a single letter "d" and, if so, replaces it with a double-d.

Answer (score 1):

I have check source code from `Zend\Form\Element\DateSelect` and it's view helper `Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormDateSelect`. The rendering date is on view helper, but it didn't use `date('j')`. It use `IntlDateFormatter` to format date, and it will output date format based on `locale` date format pattern given.

https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/release-2.2.0/src/View/Helper/FormDateSelect.php#L90

So, the solution we should pass the locale date format that use two digits day (`dd`). For country date format list, can be check here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country

Based on the date format on list above, **India** use `DD-MM-YY` as date format.  we can use this `locale` to get two digit day format,.

So, please use this on your view helper

```
echo $this->formDateSelect($form->get('date_of_birth'), IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, 'en_IN');
```

Comment: I am using the same view script for multiple pages / forms. Because of this, I am rendering the form using: `echo $this->form($form);`. Is there any way in the form/fieldset to set the `pattern` for this element?

Comment: You can keep using the same view script, but don't use `$this->form()` helper for rendering form. Just render the `$form` manually, here the example:

https://gist.github.com/dollyaswin/a0a195460f4d7d72f570a9aa651750c7

Comment: Currently I am using this same view for three different forms. Each form is having one or more fieldsets added dynamically, meaning I would have to add any number of `if` statements, followed by a tonne of `echo $this->formXXX()` functions.